# DATE_FORMAT="%s" cannot post timestamp data into datetime field

Tags: eve

I would like to use timestamp for datetime field type, so I changed DATE_FORMAT for "%s":

settings.py:

```
DATE_FORMAT="%s"
...
   'when': {
     'type': 'datetime'
    },
...
```

The format is now a valid timestamp when doing a GET on some data :

```
$ curl http://192.168.3.42:5001/stock
...
      "when": "1551083317",
...
```

BUT I cannot insert new data, datetime are not accepted :

```
$ curl -d '{"when": "1555543177"}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' http://192.168.3.42:5001/stock

{"_status": "ERR", "_issues": {"when": "must be of datetime type"}, "_error": {"code": 422, "message": "Insertion failure: 1 document(s) contain(s) error(s)"}}
```

I tried without double-quote :

```
 curl -d '{"when": 1555543177}...
```

same result.

Different formats for DATE_FORMAT are OK except for "%s" (timestamp)

any idea ?

---

$ pip list 
Package       Version

---

Cerberus      1.2
Eve           0.8.1
Flask         1.0.2
pymongo       3.7.2